# How to deal with an accepted answer that is not answering the question?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, ethics

I recently came across [a question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/148719/94491) in Workplace SE where the accepted answer does not provide a solution to the question.

From the most upvoted comment on the answer,

> I'm curious how this is the accepted answer, when it doesn't actually
>   answer the question. I mean, the OP is asking "How do I deal with
>   this" and "How can I politely ask this" - and this doesn't actually
>   say anything about how to deal with it or how to ask them it.

Someone has already commented that they are flagging it as "Not an answer". Is it valid to flag an accepted answer this way? If not, what should we do?

Comment: Downvotes might be because people think that answer is valid. Didn't check it myself yet, but +1 for a valid discussion, even if already discussed before.

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard Okay. Thank you for pointing towards the question.

Comment: Well, the accepted answer is an answer. NAA flag should be declined. It's just an unpopular answer, but still it gives the question author advise what to do: to not accept the things as they are, and not just "move on" as probably the other answers suggest. (Didn't read them)

Comment: Accepted answers and how useful they might be are at the discretion of the OP. While we might not see it as helpful, it might have been for them - which isn't really for anyone else to decide.

Comment: See here for [an example where the accepted answer is clearly wrong](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/432371/what-do-you-call-this-clamp-in-english/432372#432372). People are *allowed* to be wrong, and thus obviously not answer the question, as long as they ***try*** to answer then it's an answer. The OP has the right to choose the wrong answer as the Accepted Answer, similarly bounties can be awarded to a *bad* answer. - Usually you can rely on upvotes to direct you to the best answer, sometimes that doesn't work either, sometimes a new answer with few upvotes is actually correct.